# what's wrong with this python append to a list of dicts?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, syntax-error

Brain fart time and I can't work out what's causing a SyntaxError:

```
self.list_stuff = []
self.list_stuff.append({'A':a, 
    'B':b, 
    'C':c, 
    'D':d})
```

Comment: There is no syntax error, actually if you just copy this fragment then self does not exist, but I assume it is a fragment. Probably a, b, c and d are also defined above. Actually even then I don't know what you really want.
You try to create a list now with only one element (which is a dictionary).

Comment: That would not be a SyntaxError.

Comment: There's no `SyntaxError` in the code you posted.  Probably a closing paren is missing on the line(s) before this code.

Comment: What exactly is the traceback for the error you're getting?

Comment: Also note that you should *always include the full backtrace when reporting an error*.  Otherwise we are usually down to guessing, just as in this case.

Comment: @Triptych: Wouldn't it be `NameError: global name '<var>' is not defined`?

Comment: @GWW, Yes, it would be a NameError, not a SyntaxError. Remember that Exceptions have types in Python.

Comment: Correct, but there is no syntax error in it as written above.

Answer (score 1):

As written, this snippet has no syntax errors. We need more context to see the problem.

```
#test.py

class Foo:
   def __init__(self, a=1, b=2, c=3, d=4):

      self.list_stuff = []
      self.list_stuff.append({'A':a, 
          'B':b, 
          'C':c, 
          'D':d})

foo = Foo()
```